# RavenDB PeriodicExport Error "RequestEntityTooLarge"

Tags: c#, .net, azure, ravendb

We created **PeriodicExport** for RavenDB database. We try to upload backup files to Azure BLOB Container.

There are our settings:
[image]

In the Azure BLOB Container I can see **incremental** backup files. But I do not see **full** backups files.

Also I can see next error form the Raven Alerts:

| **Label** | **Description** |
| --- | --- |
| **Title** | Error in Periodic Export |
| **Message** | `Status code: RequestEntityTooLarge <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>RequestBodyTooLarge</Code><Message>The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit. RequestId:8b013757-401e-0014-4965-b7e992000000 Time:2021-10-02T08:13:54.8562742Z</Message><MaxLimit>67108864</MaxLimit></Error>` |
| **Level** | Error |

And there is full exception information:

```
Raven.Abstractions.Connection.ErrorResponseException: Status code: RequestEntityTooLarge
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>RequestBodyTooLarge</Code><Message>The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.
RequestId:8b013757-401e-0014-4965-b7e992000000
Time:2021-10-02T08:13:54.8562742Z</Message><MaxLimit>67108864</MaxLimit></Error>

   at Raven.Database.Client.Azure.RavenAzureClient.PutBlob(String containerName, String key, Stream stream, Dictionary`2 metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Client\Azure\RavenAzureClient.cs:line 93
   at Raven.Database.Bundles.PeriodicExports.PeriodicExportTask.UploadToAzure(String backupPath, PeriodicExportSetup localExportConfigs, Boolean isFullBackup) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Bundles\PeriodicExports\PeriodicBackupTask.cs:line 397
   at Raven.Database.Bundles.PeriodicExports.PeriodicExportTask.<>c__DisplayClasse.<<TimerCallback>b__a>d__10.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Bundles\PeriodicExports\PeriodicBackupTask.cs:line 248
```

Raven DB version is:

```
{
  "ProductVersion": "3.0.0 / cdc39ac / ",
  "BuildVersion": "3690"
}
```

It is possible to fix this error?

Any help is much appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

I have found source code of the relevant build version in GitHub [repository](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/releases/tag/build-3690).

The bug exists in the next method:

```
public void PutBlob(string containerName, string key, Stream stream, Dictionary<string, string> metadata)
{
    var url = GetUrl(containerName) + "/" + key;

    var now = SystemTime.UtcNow;
    var content = new StreamContent(stream)
                  {
                      Headers =
                      {
                          { "x-ms-date", now.ToString("R") }, 
                          { "x-ms-version", "2011-08-18" },
                          { "x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob" },
                          { "Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }
                      }
                  };

    foreach (var metadataKey in metadata.Keys)
        content.Headers.Add("x-ms-meta-" + metadataKey.ToLower(), metadata[metadataKey]);

    var client = GetClient(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CalculateAuthorizationHeaderValue("PUT", url, content.Headers);

    var response = client.PutAsync(url, content).ResultUnwrap();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return;

    throw ErrorResponseException.FromResponseMessage(response);
}
```

As you can see this method use Azure API version **2011-08-18**. Limitations for this Azure version described in the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-blob-storage-limits).

Regarding documentation "**Maximum blob size via single write operation (via Put Blob)**" is exactly **64 MiB** (67108864 bytes). So exception provided by Azure is absolutely correct.

Unfortunately Raven Build-3690 has a bug, that was fixed in the next version. Source code with fixes can be reviewed [here](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.0/Raven.Database/Client/Azure/RavenAzureClient.cs#L80).

Comment: This should work in v3.5.
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.5/Raven.Database/Client/Azure/RavenAzureClient.cs#L36
Note that v3.0 and v3.5 are out of support.

Comment: @GrishaKotler thanks. But I have compared RavenAzureClient class between versions [3.0](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.0/Raven.Database/Client/Azure/RavenAzureClient.cs) and [3.5](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.5/Raven.Database/Client/Azure/RavenAzureClient.cs). And source code of these classes are identical.

Comment: Build `3690` is from 2015. You need to use the latest stable. (3.0 or 3.5)

Comment: Is there any updates on this question? Did this answer resolved your question?

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT please review update.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT is exists any way to increase "Maximum blob size via single write operation (via Put Blob)" limit for BLOB storage? Maybe we can migrate storage to the new version or something like it? Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is exists any way to increase "Maximum blob size via single write
> operation (via Put Blob)" limit for BLOB storage?

The limits can not be change because its designed.

Based on the [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account#scale-targets-for-standard-storage-accounts) :

> Azure Storage standard accounts support higher capacity limits and
> higher limits for ingress and egress by request. To request an
> increase in account limits, contact [Azure
> Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/support/faq/).

As you said , here is the table describes the maximum block and blob sizes permitted by service version.
[image]

For more information please refer this Azure Blog:  [Run high scale workloads on Blob storage with new 200 TB object sizes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/run-high-scale-workloads-on-blob-storage-with-new-200-tb-object-sizes/)